Degree one meromorphic $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ mapping which is doubly quasi-periodic?
I am interested in functions $f$ which are meromorphic (depend only on $z$) and are almost (or quasi) periodic in the sense
$$f(z+1) = e^{i\phi(z)} f(z),\qquad f(z+\tau) = e^{i\psi(z)}f(z)$$
where $\phi,\psi$ are real functions and $f$ is degree one (has a single pole and a single zero per ``fundamental domain"). If I allow that $f$ is degree two, of course there are elliptic functions which satisfy this with $\phi(z) = \psi(z) = 0$. I want to know if similar results can be obtained for degree one.
For context, I am interested because using the stereographic projection onto a sphere to get a unit vector $\vec n[f]$, this would define a skyrmion texture (with one skyrmion per unit cell) with "nice" energetic properties when we consider the natural Hamiltonian $H=\frac12\int \sum_{i=x,y}(\partial_i \vec n[f])^2$.

A continuous function $\phi$ satisfying $f(z+1) = e^{i\phi(z)} f(z)$ is locally holomorphic. If $\phi$ is also real-valued then it is necessarily constant.

Also $|f(z+1)/f(z)| = 1$ implies that the quotient is constant (all singularities are removable, and then Liouville's theorem can be applied).

@MartinR I see, thank you. So we've reduced my question down to the case when $\phi$ and $\psi$ are both constants.
